# Why this python character sequence code giving unexpected result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, frequency

I am writing a python program to find character sequence in a word. But the program is giving the unexpected result.
I have found a similar type program that works perfectly.
To me I think the two program is quite similar but dont know why one of them does not work

1. The program that is not working:

```py
# Display the character sequence in a word
dict={}
string=input("Enter the string:").strip().lower()

for letter in string:
    if letter !=dict.keys():
        dict[letter]=1        
    else:
        dict[letter]=dict[letter]+1

print(dict)
```

2. The program that is working:

```py
def char_frequency(str1):
    dict = {}
    for n in str1:
        keys = dict.keys()
        if n in keys:
            dict[n] += 1
        else:
            dict[n] = 1
    return dict

print(char_frequency('google.com'))
```

1. The output for the first program is giving:

Enter the string:google.com

```py
{'g': 1, 'c': 1, 'm': 1, 'o': 1, 'l': 1, '.': 1, 'e': 1}
```

2. The output for the second program is:

`{'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'o': 3, 'g': 2, '.': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1}`

The above is the correct output.

Now the questions in my mind.

i. Why the first program is not working correctly?

ii. Is the ideology of these two programs are different?

Comment: Side-note: The canonical solution here would be `return collections.Counter(str1)`, because counting iterables is a solved problem (in modern Python, `Counter` has a C accelerator that runs faster than anything you could write by hand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's a little mistake is in the if statement you have used. Just have a look at the below modified program.

> **Note:** Also make sure not to use pre-defined data type names like **dict** as variable names. I have changed that to **d** here.

```
>>> d = {}
>>>
>>> string=input("Enter the string:").strip().lower()
Enter the string:google.com
>>> 
>>> for letter in string:
...     if letter not in d.keys():
...         d[letter] = 1        
...     else:
...         d[letter] = d[letter] + 1
... 
>>> print(d)
{'g': 2, 'o': 3, 'l': 1, 'e': 1, '.': 1, 'c': 1, 'm': 1}
>>>
```

You can have also have a look at the below statements executed on the terminal.

Comparing a **key** with **d.keys()** will always return `False` as **key** is a string here and **d.keys()** will always be an object of type `dict_keys` (Python3) and a `list` (Python2).

```
>>> d = {"k1": "v1", "k3": "v2", "k4": "Rishi"}
>>> 
>>> d.keys()
dict_keys(['k1', 'k3', 'k4'])
>>> 
>>> "k1" in d
True
>>> 
>>> not "k1" in d
False
>>> 
>>> "k1" == d.keys()
False
>>> 
>>> "k1" not in d
False
>>>
```

Answers of your 2 questions:

1. Because the statement `letter != dict.keys()` is always `True` so no increment in key counts. Just change it to `letter not in dict.keys()`. And it is better to use `d` in place of `dict` so that the statement will look like `letter not in d.keys()`.
2. Logic of both the programs are same i.e. iterating over the dictionary, checking for an existence of key in dictionary. If it does not exist,  create a new key with count `1` else increment the related count by `1`.

Thank you v. much.

Comment: To read like English, it's usually preferred to use `x not in y`, rather than `not x in y`. They behave equivalently, but the former reads more clearly. Python's PEP8 only specifically addresses it for `is` (where `x is not y` is preferred explicitly over `not x is y`), but the same principle applies.

Comment: You mate make me learn. Thank me very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

This line is nonsensical:

```
if letter !=dict.keys():
```

`letter` is a length one `str`, while `dict.keys()` returns a key view object, which is guaranteed to never be equal to a `str` of any kind. Your `if` check is *always* false. The correct logic would be:

```
if letter not in dict:
```

(you could add `.keys()` if you really want to, but it's wasteful and pointless; membership testing on a `dict` is checking its keys implicitly).

Side-note: You're going to confuse the crap out of yourself by naming a variable `dict`, because you're name-shadowing the `dict` constructor; if you ever need to use it, it won't be available in that scope. Don't shadow built-in names if at all possible.

Comment: Your answer made me to know some core of python. Thank you very much for your time.